# Peewee group_by Unexpected Results

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, orm, aggregate, peewee

When grouping in [Peewee](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#aggregating-records), the SQL generated by Peewee for the query if run directly in Mysql returns ***53*** properly aggregated records by year and month for the first database.

##### Peewee Generated SQL

```
SELECT 
    1 AS `id`, 
    'db_anon_a' AS `db_name`, 
    'Anon A' AS `name`, 
    YEAR(`t1`.`occurred_at`) AS `year`, 
    MONTH(`t1`.`occurred_at`) AS `month_number`, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.`occurred_at`, '%M') AS `month_name`, 
    SUM(`t1`.`count`) AS `event_count` 
FROM `events` AS `t1` 
WHERE (`t1`.`occurred_at` >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY year, month_number, month_name;
```

However, if executed in Python with Peewee, only ***7*** records are returned for the first database. No error, but obviously not the correct results.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "db_name": "db_anon_a",
        "name": "Anon A",
        "year": "2023",
        "month_number": "4",
        "month_name": "April",
        "event_count": Decimal("107521"),
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "db_name": "db_anon_a",
        "name": "Anon A",
        "year": "2023",
        "month_number": "6",
        "month_name": "June",
        "event_count": Decimal("67292"),
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "db_name": "db_anon_a",
        "name": "Anon A",
        "year": "2023",
        "month_number": "1",
        "month_name": "January",
        "event_count": Decimal("66779"),
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "db_name": "db_anon_a",
        "name": "Anon A",
        "year": "2023",
        "month_number": "2",
        "month_name": "February",
        "event_count": Decimal("44289"),
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "db_name": "db_anon_a",
        "name": "Anon A",
        "year": "2023",
        "month_number": "3",
        "month_name": "March",
        "event_count": Decimal("69339"),
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "db_name": "db_anon_a",
        "name": "Anon A",
        "year": "2023",
        "month_number": "5",
        "month_name": "May",
        "event_count": Decimal("115950"),
    },
]
```

I thought possibly I needed to use the database as a context manager to prevent the connection closing prematurely, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

##### Problem code

```
E = globals()["events"]

year = fn.YEAR(E.occurred_at)
month_number = fn.MONTH(E.occurred_at)
month_name = fn.DATE_FORMAT(E.occurred_at, '%M')
event_count = fn.SUM(E.count)

query = (
    E.select(
        Value(row['id']).alias('id'),
        Value(row['db_name']).alias('db_name'),
        Value(row['name']).alias('name'),
        year.alias('year'),
        month_number.alias('month_number'),
        month_name.alias('month_name'),
        event_count.alias('event_count')
    )
    .where(E.occurred_at >= datetime(2019, 1, 1))
    .group_by(SQL('year'), SQL('month_number'), SQL('month_name'))
)

x = list(query)
y = list(query.dicts()))

df = pd.DataFrame(query.dicts())
```

The code is part of a larger function meant to iterate tenant databases which are provided in a Dataframe (df). There are about 20 tenants. To avoid introspecting every database, I rebind each database to the models introspected from the first database.

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional, Tuple

import pandas as pd
from peewee import SQL, fn, Value

from app.database import get_models, get_db


def query_all_event_volume(df):

    db = None
    models = None
    results = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if db is not None:
            db.close()
            print(f'Closed {db_name} db')

        db_name = row['db_name']

        if 'events' not in globals().keys():
            print(f'Generating events models from {db_name} db')
            load_models(db_name, tables=('events',))
            db = globals()['events']._meta.database
        else:
            db = get_db(db_name)
            print(f'Binding events to {db_name} db')
            globals()['events'].bind(db)

        print(f"Querying: {row['db_name']}.events for volume by month")

        E = globals()['events']

        year = fn.YEAR(E.occurred_at)
        month_number = fn.MONTH(E.occurred_at)
        month_name = fn.DATE_FORMAT(E.occurred_at, '%M')
        event_count = fn.SUM(E.count)

        query = (
            E.select(
                Value(row['id']).alias('id'),
                Value(row['db_name']).alias('db_name'),
                Value(row['name']).alias('name'),
                year.alias('year'),
                month_number.alias('month_number'),
                month_name.alias('month_name'),
                event_count.alias('events')
            )
            .where(E.occurred_at >= datetime(2019, 1, 1))
            .group_by(SQL('year'), SQL('month_number'), SQL('month_name'))
        )

        x = list(query)
        print(list(query.dicts()))

        df = pd.DataFrame(query.dicts())

        results.append(df)

    return pd.concat(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to group by the first 3 columns as well, won't you? You might try modifying:

```
    query = (
        E.select(
            Value(row['id']).alias('id'),
            Value(row['db_name']).alias('db_name'),
            Value(row['name']).alias('name'),
            year.alias('year'),
            month_number.alias('month_number'),
            month_name.alias('month_name'),
            event_count.alias('events')
        )
        .where(E.occurred_at >= datetime(2019, 1, 1))
        .group_by(
          SQL('id'), SQL('db_name'), SQL('name'),
          SQL('year'), SQL('month_number'), SQL('month_name'))
    )
```

Example of working code:

```
db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Event(db.Model):
    name = TextField()
    date = DateField()

db.create_tables([Event])

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        Event.create(
            name='e%s' % i,
            date=datetime.date(2023, 7, i))

query = (Event
         .select(
             Event.name,
             Event.date.year.alias('year'),
             Event.date.month.alias('month'),
             fn.COUNT(Event.id).alias('count'))
         .group_by(Event.name, SQL('year'), SQL('month'))
         .order_by(Event.name))
for row in query.dicts():
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'e1', 'year': 2023, 'month': 7, 'count': 1}
{'name': 'e2', 'year': 2023, 'month': 7, 'count': 2}
{'name': 'e3', 'year': 2023, 'month': 7, 'count': 3}
{'name': 'e4', 'year': 2023, 'month': 7, 'count': 4}
```

Last, I suggest you try producing a minimum reproduction next time...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I am still unfortunately stuck on this. When I extract the SQL query Peewee produces and run it directly in the console, I get correct results with aggregates spanning months back to 2019. However, when I examine the dataframe pd.DataFrame(list(query.dicts())) from code execution I have only a few rows in the current year, the results dont match? I've minimized the columns to only year, month_number and events and tried the group_by using SQL() on aliases as well as fn.YEAR() and fn.Month().

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue to the occurred_at column. I expected this column was a date or datetime, but unfortunately, this table was designed, not by myself, with the date stored as VARCHAR. I apologize for taking up your time on this.